# What is the maximum length of a regex expression?

Tags: regex, postgresql

In PostgreSQL, I want to exclude rows if the `desc` field contains any forbidden words.

`items`:

```
| id | desc             |
|----|------------------|
| 1  | apple foo cat bar|
| 2  | foo bar          |
| 3  | foocatbar        |
| 4  | foo dog bar      |
```

The forbidden words list is stored in another table, currently it has 400 words to check.

`forbidden_word_table`:

```
| word    |
|---------|
| apple   |
| boy     | 
| cat     | 
| dog     | 
| ....    |
```

SQL query:

```
select id, desc
from items
where
desc !~* (select '\y(' || string_agg(word, '|') || ')\y' from forbidden_word_table)
```

I am checking if `desc` does not match the regex expression:

```
desc !~* '\y(apple|boy|cat|dog|.............)\y'
```

Results:

```
| id | desc             |
|----|------------------|
| 2  | foo bar          |
| 3  | foocatbar        |
```

** 3rd is not excluded since `cat` is not a single word

My `forbidden_word_table` will likely grow with many rows, the above regex will become a very lengthy expression.

Do regex expressions have a maximum length limit (in bytes or characters)? I'm afraid of my regex matching approach will not work if `forbidden_word_table` keeps growing.

Comment: What about `where desc NOT IN (SELECT word FROM forbidden_word_table)`?

Comment: @MaciejLos I have tried ```where desc NOT IN (SELECT word FROM forbidden_word_table)```, it can only do an exact match, it cannot exclude row 1&4 in the above example.

Comment: I don't know about postgresql, but I already used a 27kB regex of the form `(1|2|3|...)` with 5200 words in Java and that worked pretty fast.

Comment: It is likely to stop working even if there is no regex length limit. If there are a lot of words sharing the same prefix, you will run into catastrophic backtracking anyway. You need to build a regex trie from these search words.

Comment: I doubt there is a built-in limit. More likely a limit that is an artifact of the implementation or memory limits, and likely to change over time. I also suspect that what we have here is an [XY Problem](https://xyproblem.info). I recommend you change your question to the underlying need, rather than asking for help with a possibly bad solution.

Comment: What about that [db-fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_10&fiddle=eec9dacc19ff345d3dc2024e432ebdd2)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems, that [Wiktor Stribiżew](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3832970/wiktor-stribi%c5%bcew) is right about "catastrophic backtracking".

I'd suggest to use [ILIKE](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-matching.html) and [ANY](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-comparisons.html#id-1.5.8.30.16):

```
SELECT *
FROM items i
WHERE NOT i."desc" ILIKE ANY
(
  SELECT '%' || word || '%'
  FROM forbidden_word_table
);
```

[db-fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_10&fiddle=303ccc3a0e3cfd8aa2ed99ecbe8916db)